# Strongloop Loopback dataSource.disconnect no longer disconnects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

This automigrate.js script used to work fine, but now it hangs without exiting with new strongloop version.

Strongloop folks, what changed that this no longer exits? Trying to set up automated deployment but this is a blocker.

```
var path = require('path');
var app  = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../server'));
var _    = require('lodash');

// fix for (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected
require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 100;

var dataSource = app.dataSources.mysqlDB;

dataSource.autoupdate([
    'Person'
  ], function(err) {

  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log('closing pool'); // this echoes but...
  dataSource.disconnect();     // ...script never exits

});
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "no longer exits", but if that is all of the code you have then there isn't anything it is doing to keep this code running. The [`dataSource.disconnect()` method](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/9083370e175c3d07ed19facdc709c5d2c987e10e/lib/datasource.js#L1745-L1757) just calls the mysql connector's `disconnect()` method which in turn just calls the mysql library's [`end()` method](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/blob/2a249beb77ecd3cb24c38071ab22629e290a1353/lib/mysql.js#L1288-L1295).

Comment: What I mean is the script hangs, does not exit with 0 like it used to as-is, so it is useless when run via fabric or over ssh for automation (the next command after this file will never run). Per strongloop folks it might be due to the newest node mysql driver not playing nice.

Comment: Ah, well, I'm glad you've contacted the support folks, it's unfortunate that we're at the whim of the node DB drivers, but not much we can do about it. Please update this if it gets resolved!

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution to this yet? I'm using MongoDB and experiencing the same issue too.

Comment: @uzyn yeah, I am using `process.exit(0);` to force the issue as a workaround, but still no real fix or root cause for this.

Comment: @Brian Thanks. Will do the same for now. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Brian — If you submitted an issue to the Loopback team, could you please link it here in the comments? Seems like quite a bunch of us who landed on this question would like to follow resolution progress.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disconnect after datasource is connected. Try this :

```
var path = require('path');
var app = require(path.join(__dirname,"..","server","server"));
var ds = app.datasources.mysql;
ds.once('connected', function() {
    ds.disconnect();
    console.log("here");
});
```